# How do I tell Jersey where my MessageBodyWriter is?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I'm working with Jersey (jaxrs-ri-2.7), Tomcat 7.0.47 and Java 1.7.0_51.  Due to firewalls, I can't use Maven.  My goal is to do a JSON RESTful web service.  I cannot get MOXy to work though I'm told it's included with the version of Jersey.  At one point, I could get Jersey to return XML.  When I invoke my web service via a browser, this is what I get:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: 

MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class com.pracht.test.Calculation, genericType=class com.pracht.test.Calculation.

    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:247)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:571)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:378)
    ...
```

This is my provider class:

```
package com.pracht.test;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.owlike.genson.Genson;
import com.owlike.genson.TransformationException;

@Provider
@Produces("application/json")
public class JsonProvider implements MessageBodyWriter<Calculation> {

    public JsonProvider() throws IOException{
        try {
            PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(
                       new BufferedOutputStream(new  FileOutputStream("c:\\test.txt")));
            pw.println("Reached JsonProvider()");
            pw.close();
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(Calculation arg0, Class<?> arg1, Type arg2,
            Annotation[] arg3, MediaType arg4) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Calculation calculation, 
            Class<?> type, 
            Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, 
            MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, 
            OutputStream entityStream)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        Genson genson = new Genson();
        try {
            String json=genson.serialize(calculation);
            entityStream.write(json.getBytes());
        } catch (TransformationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new WebApplicationException("Serialization error",e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> classType, Type arg1, Annotation[] arg2,
            MediaType arg3) {
        return classType == Calculation.class;
    }


}
```

I added the PrintWriter in the constructor to *hopefully* tell me that least an object got constructed and to put the results where I can see it.  I just wanted something quick and didn't want to figure out whatever logging API happens to be in use.

This is my web resource:

```
package com.pracht.test;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/calc")
public class CalcRest {


public CalcRest(){
    System.out.println("Reached CalcRest()");

}

@GET
@Path("/add/{a}/{b}")
@Produces("application/json")
public Calculation addPlainText(@PathParam("a") double a,
        @PathParam("b") double b) {
    System.out.println("Reached addPlainText()");
    return new Calculation().withProblem(a+"+"+b).withAnswer(a+b);
}

}
```

This is the call I make using Firefox:

```
http://localhost:8080/Contacts/rest/calc/add/1/2
```

As a side note, would Java developers like it if there were just *one* library which actually handled JSON web services using annotations, out of the box.  One that just worked?

Comment: There's no need to write custom MessageBodyWriter. What You need to do is to just set the property `com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature` to `true` in the provider.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you write a MessageBodyWriter for Genson? Genson has its own that should be picked automatically when you have Genson in your classpath.

If it is not the case I guess that Jersey finds another provider for JSON (moxy perhaps) and thus doesn't pick Genson. If this is the case you can try to create a folder META-INF/services in your classpath and define there Genson as your provider (this should override the other providers). You can have a look at how it is done in Genson [here](https://code.google.com/p/genson/source/browse/#git%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fresources%2FMETA-INF%2Fservices).

Also you should take latest version of Genson, 0.99, it has a couple of improvments such as the implementation of JSR 353 that tries to provide a "standard" for JSON Parsing (not databinding) in Java.